# How to get the selected value from the drop down list in MVC 4 and assign that value to another local variable for comparison variable

Tags: razor

My Razor View

[image: My Razor View]

I want to get the selected value of securityReq_C

```
@{
    var listItems = new List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem>
    { 
        new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem{Text ="1",Value="1"},
        new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem{Text ="2",Value="2"},
        new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem{Text ="3",Value="3"}
    };
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.addasset.securityReq_C, new SelectList(listItems, "Value",   "Text"), "N/A", new { id = "selectError6", onchange = "getAlldata()" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have this list on your model and bind the list to your dropdownListFor. You also need to "submit" this somehow i dont know if you use html.BeginForm  or ajax.beginform or some other submit function but you will requier to submit the values somehow to your controller. Last but not least you need some function in your Controller to deal with the post from your form or whatever you send back to the controller.

VIEW

```
    using (Ajax.BeginForm("ACTION", "CONTROLLER", new AjaxOptions()
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                OnBegin = "",
                OnComplete = "",
                UpdateTargetId = "TargetDivToBeUpdated"
            }))
            {
 //Your dropdown Goes inside form

    };
```

CONTROLLER

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ACTION(MODEL)
{
    //Logic
}
```

MODEL

```
public class YoURViewModeL
{
    public YOuRList { get; set; }
}
```